# Accessing SQL data using Google Cloud Postgres for App Engine (python)

Tags: python, postgresql, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I have a google cloud Postgres database and I can query it no problem in a jupyter notebook. I created a connection to the database using psycopg2. However, I am building a web app with flask and it seems that I cannot use psycopg2 in the gcloud run deploy. I've read the documentation on pg8000 but I am very confused. I am very new to this.

What is the simplest function to create a connection to the database so I can query the data?

This is what I was using with psycopg2:

```
#establishing the connection
conn = psycopg2.connect(
   database='postgres', user='postgres', password='password', host='Public IP Address', port='5432')
```

Then I could fetch data using:

```
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT STMT')
result = cursor.fetchall()
```

Any help or direction is much appreciated.

Comment: See documentation for how to connect to PostgreSQL from App Engine Standard - https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-app-engine-standard

Comment: What are you dependencies? Do you have Network Access restriction on your Cloud SQL database?